# Passing URL for texture through props in react-three-fibre

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

I have recently started using react-three-fibre and I have discovered [this example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-three-fiber-map-mkq8e?from-embed) Where the svg image is loaded through the component rather than directly in the function. I wanted to use this idea since I want to reuse the same component but implement different urls to load different textures.

I have tried to copy what this example did but it keeps coming up with the error:
**Cannot GET /undefined**
Here is my code:

```
import * as THREE from "three";
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import React, { Suspense, useState, useRef, useEffect, useMemo } from 'react'
import { Canvas, extend, useLoader, useThree, useFrame } from 'react-three-fiber'



function Box(props, {url}) {
    const [texture] = useLoader(THREE.TextureLoader, url);

    const mesh = useRef()


    const [hover, setHover] = useState(false)


    return (

      <mesh
        {...props}
        ref={mesh}
        castShadow
        rotation={props.rotation} 
        scale={hover ? [1.2, 1, 1.2] : [1, 1, 1]}

        onPointerOver={e => setHover(true)}
        onPointerOut={e => setHover(false)}>

        <boxBufferGeometry attach="geometry" args={[130,.1,120]} />
        <meshStandardMaterial attach="material" map = {texture} transparent = {true} />
      </mesh>

    )
  }


function App() {
  return (
    <Canvas camera={{ position: [5,300,0],  
        fov:60, 
        aspect: window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 
        near:1, 
        far: 1000 }}>
        <Suspense fallback={null}>

            <Box position={[150, 10, -340]} rotation = {[0, Math.PI/2,0]} url = {['../../URL']}/>
            <Box position={[0, 0, 0]} />

      </Suspense>

       <directionalLight position = {[1,1,1]} intensity = {[1.7]}/>
    </Canvas>
  )
}


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

I have also tried to pass the url through `props.url` instead of using just `url` but this also comes with a similar error and I don't know how to rectify this. I have looked through the docs [here](https://github.com/react-spring/react-three-fiber) for react-three-fiber and it seems maybe this only works for other loaders? such as Draco or GLTF. But I don't know why it wouldn't work for TextureLoader.

EDIT:
Full error:
[image]
[image]

So it's not the most useful error as it creates a separate html page saying it cannot get/undefined. It does have something to do with passing the url since if I directly implement the full url inside the function everything works fine. But I don't want to be creating so many different functions. I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32467408/http-localhost-undefined-404-not-found) with someone with a similar error and it suggested that maybe Javascript had set my src to undefined? But it shouldn't since it works perfectly fine if the url isn't passed through props. So i'm guessing my syntax is wrong but I don't know how to correct it.

Comment: Please post the full text of the error, including what file/line it came from.

Comment: @TheJim01 Thank you for your comment. I have added the full error in the edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line seems like it's causing the issue:

`const [texture] = useLoader(THREE.TextureLoader, url);`

`useLoader` will not be able to read `url` as it is an array, and it will return the texture as an object so destructuring it as an array is not going to work.

The texture url needs to be held in the `public` folder and accessed however you access public in your environment. I think this is where the `cannot GET` issue stems from - the file requesting the texture does not have correct access to the public folder.

From there it's just a case of passing the path string down as a prop, and you can do this as a standalone string or as part of an array if necessary. In my example, this was:

`<Box url={["/plainmap.jpg"]} />`

To access that string in the texture loader you need to specify the index or use the spread operator.

`const texture = useLoader(THREE.TextureLoader, ...url);`

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-blackwell-4k0wx)

Comment: Hi @lawrence-witt thank you for your comment. The only reason why i'm using `url` is because it was what the above example used with the svg loader and I wanted to utilise this method since I want to define the url as props on the components themselves rather than inside the function so I would be able to reuse the components and have different textures for each of them. I don't know another way of doing this.

Comment: If you look at the example you posted, it shows the Svg element is being passed `url` as a string. If you change your code to match the syntax shown in the example I believe this should be fine - although there is no need to destructure the texture at all once it has been loaded.

Comment: Also, a general note if this does not work, usually when you get a `cannot GET` message it means you are being denied by whatever server is supplying the file. If you're in a local environment this might mean the file is outside the scope of the project.

Comment: I have tried the syntax exactly the same as the example showed but it displayed the error nonetheless. I don't know why it would be a server issue since If i load it directly e.g. `const [texture] = useLoader(THREE.TextureLoader, ['../../url.png']);` it loads perfectly fine I just need to pass it through a string from the component

Comment: Alright I've been playing around with this in a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-blackwell-4k0wx) for a while now and I cannot get the textureLoader to parse a string as props. In fact I can't get it to parse any string, which has actually been my experience in the past now that I think about it. What I usually do is import the texture at the top of the main file and than pass that import down as a prop. Checkout the sandbox and I'll update my answer - hopefully this is ok for your use case!

Comment: Ok, scratch that, I did get it working as you wanted. The sandbox should now have the updated version and I'll update my answer again. Three.js has been scrambling my brain for the last month so I apologise, lol...

Comment: So I realised that the main issue for triggering the error was using props along with {textureSrc} in `function Box(props, { textureSrc}) {...CODE..}` I was stubbornly trying to use props to set the position and rotation of the components. The way around it was to instead use `function Icons({ textureSrc, BoxPosition })` and then state `<mesh position = {BoxPosition}>...</mesh> and then put in the values for `BoxPosition` in the component.

Comment: Thank you so so much for your time and help. This was really winding me up so please don't apologise. You really saved me here so thank you again!